# Mobile dropdown nav won't close on mobile once opened

Tags: navigation, jekyll, frontend

My out of the box Jekyll dropdown Nav won't close on mobile once opened. I tried tapping on the body of the site but it won't close, you have to click a link. This happens on iPhone not sure about Andriod.Can this be fixed with Jquery or have I broken something? the site is [link](http://www.statsbombservices.com/)

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/#so-what-is-jekyll-exactly) issue, it's related to the them used to create your website, (generated by jekyll).

so No, I don't think that you've broken any jekyll thing.

to fix the drop-down component, start by inspecting your code source:

```html
<div class="trigger">...</div> <!-- this is the supposedly stubborn div :)  -->
```

you can fix this, after identifying the issue, either by using javascript, jquery, a pre-built component form a library such as [material design light](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section) or you can go with a pure [css solution](http://codepen.io/nwest88/pen/PwwZpv), the call is yours.

btw, because I can't reproduce the bug, and there is no much information about it I can't suggest a specific solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. really appreciate ut

Comment: you're welcome, and welcome in stack overflow.
if you consider the answer as correct please mark it as such, to close the question, (or you can wait a bit more, to see if you get better answers)